# Curvature and adjoint bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\pi:P\to M$ a principal $G$-bundle. A **connection** $A$ on $P$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued one-form, i.e. an element of $\Omega^1(P)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$, satisfying some properties. The **curvature** $F$ of $A$ is an element of $\Omega^2(P)\otimes\mathfrak{g}$ defined by
$$F(X,Y)=dA(X^H,Y^H)$$
where $X,Y$ are vector fields on $P$ and $X^H,Y^H$ their horizontal components.

Some texts say that the curvature can be seen as an element of $\Omega^2(\mathrm{ad}(P))$ where $\mathrm{ad}(P):=P\times_G\mathfrak{g}$ is the vector bundle associated to the adjoint representation. How to see this? What element of $\Omega^2(P\times_G\mathfrak{g})$ precisely? And how can we recover the original curvature from it?

Comment: From physics perspective, the answer to your first question is quite obvious. The curvature tensor $F$ corresponds to the field strength in Yang-Mills theory. Under a gauge transformation $U$, the vector potential transforms as $A\rightarrow U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}AU$, and the field strength transforms as $U^{-1}FU$, which is indeed a $2$-form transforming in the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 0):

The connection $A$ is a tensorial $1$-form i.e $g\in G, R_g^*A=Ad(g^{-1})A$. This implies that the covariant derivative of $A$ which is the curvature is a tensorial 2-form. i.e $R_g^*F=Ad(g^{-1})F$. This is equivalent to saying that $F\in \Omega^2(P\times_G\mathfrak{g})$. To see this, consider the trivialization $(U_i\times G)$ of $P$. Suppose that the transition functions of $P$ are defined by $u_{ij}$, the transition functions of $P\times_G\mathfrak{g}$ are defined by $Ad(u_{ij}^{-1})$, Let $x\in U_i\cap U_j\times G, u,v\in T_x(U_i\cap U_j\times G)$, the transition function sends $x$ to $xu_{ij}$ and $u$ to $R_{u_{ij}}^*u$ we deduce that $F_{xu_{ij}}(R_{u_{ij}}^*u,R_{u_{ij}}^*v)=Ad(u_{ij}^{-1})F(u,v)$ since $F$ is tensorial. This is the local definition of an element of $\Omega^2(P\times_G\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect – in order for a form be tensorial, not only must it fulfill the condition you state (which $A$ does), it must also vanish whenever any of its arguments is vertical (which $A$ does not; indeed, it fixes the fundamental vector fields). What is true, then, is that the difference of two connection forms is tensorial. On the other hand, the curvature form is tensorial.

Comment: Since the curvature form on $P$ is tensorial of type $\mathrm{Ad} : G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathfrak{g})$, the well-known correspondence between tensorial $k$-forms on $P$ of type $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ on the one hand, and $E := P \times_\rho V$-valued $k$-forms on $M$ on the other, answers your question. This correspondence is merely a generalization of the obvious one between the global sections $M \to E$ of $E := P \times_\rho V$ and $G$-equivariant maps $P \to V$.

Comment: The connection $1$-form is NOT tensorial. Under a gauge transformation, a connection $1$-form $A$ transforms as $A\rightarrow U^{-1}dU+U^{-1}AU$.